# How to Avoid Committing Tokens in GIT when doing Angular project?

Tags: angular

Please explain how to avoid adding `environment/*` to git

I have created new project using Angular CLI. And I have some very sensitive token which I wanted to avoid add that `environment/environment.ts` in Git.

Comment: so do you not want to track `environments` folder?

Comment: Yes or is there any other way around ?

Comment: Are you using AWS to deploy the code.If not then what thing are you using for deployment of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create `.gitignore` text file in your project root folder and add `environment` in it and when you commit your code, environment folder will be ignored.